# Проверка на видимость блока в jquery

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-form

Добрый день! Есть наполовину рабочий код, не могу понять, где ошибка.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
        $("#login-content").toggle("slide");
       
    });
  

if ($("#login-content2").is(":hidden")){

  $('#signup').click(function () {
         $("#login-content2").toggle("slide")
         $("#login-content").hide();
    });
   
}
   else{
   $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
         $('#login-content2').hide();         
       });
   }

      
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background: #2980b9;
}
nav li {
  float: left;          
}

nav #login-trigger{
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
#signup{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

nav #login-content, #login-content2{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 15px;
}

nav li #login-content, #login-content2{
  right: 46px;
  width: 250px;
}

/*--------------------*/


#login #submit {
  background: #2980b9;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

#login #submit:hover,
#login #submit:focus {
  background-color: #1476b7;
} 

#login #submit:active {   
  outline: none;
}

#login #submit::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}

#login label {
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#login label input {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Flyout login form</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li id="login">
    <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
     <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="login-content">
     <form>
      <fieldset id="inputs">
       <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="email" required>   
       <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="actions">

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enter">
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> remember</label>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
           <a id="signup" href="#">SignUp</a>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>

    <div id="login-content2">
     <form>
      <fieldset id="inputs">
       <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="first name" required>  
       <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="last name" required>  
       <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="email" required>   
       <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="actions">
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enter">
       <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> remember</label>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>

   </li>
   
  </ul>
 </nav>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Логика работы такова:

Нажимаем на верхнюю квадратную кнопку и появляется форма авторизации.
Если пользователь не авторизован — нажимает регистрацию "SignUp"
Форма авторизации закрывается, открывается рега.

И теперь самое главное:

Если пользователь передумал, то при клике на тот же квадрат или в любой области экрана, где нет формы — всё должно закрываться.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы задаете для кнопки разные события *click*, исходя из того, виден ли сейчас блок. 
Попробуйте такой подход:

```
$('#signup').click(function () {
    if ($("#login-content2").is(":hidden")){
        $("#login-content2").toggle("slide");
        $("#login-content").hide();       
    }
    else
    {
        $('#login-content2').hide();            
    }
});
```

Что там в коде произошло - мы повесили на элемент **один** обработчик, который проверяет **спрятан ли элемент** и выполняет действия исходя из этого. 
В вашем случае же было так:
*Слайдим* туда-сюда **#login-content2** и постоянно прячем **#login-content**. 
При этом, обработчик *click* на **#login-trigger** не вешается, поскольку инструкция **if** выполняется только **один** раз, когда загружается страница и обработчик на **#login-trigger** скорее всего не попадет.

В том случае когда пользователь передумал:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('#content').hide();
});
```

Можно так же попробовать сделать блок-подложку на весь экран, когда у Вас вызывается модальное окно и при нажатии на него будет закрываться модальное окно, тем самым создавая нужный Вам эффект. 
Это, кстати, можно легко сделать при использовании [бутстраповских](http://bootstrap-3.ru/javascript.php) модальных окон. 
p.s. Код не гарантированно рабочий - но направить Вас я думаю должен.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Вот только не могу решить след. действие:


"Если пользователь передумал, то при клике на тот же квадрат или в любой области экрана, где нет формы — всё должно закрываться."

При нажатии на пустую область закрывается всё, а при нажатии на квадрат —  появляется форма авторизации вновь

Comment: После else я добавил:

$('#login-content').hide(); 

То есть и вторая и первая должна закрываться. Но первая всё равно всплывает.

Comment: @ArtemManzhos попробуйте ее принудительно скрывать добавив: $('#login-content').css('display','none');

Comment: Я понял почему! Мы сделали один раз .hide(); и после этого оно еще раз не может быть хайд, ибо вернулось в дэфолтное положение и вновь открывается по клику!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  
    $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
      $('.fon').fadeIn(0);
        $("#login-content").toggle("slide");
       $("#login-content2").hide(0); // при нажатии на квадрат прячем вторую форму
    });
  
  $('#signup').click(function () {
         $("#login-content2").toggle("slide");
         $("#login-content").hide();
    });
  
  $('.fon').click(function () { // при нажатии на пустую область прячем все
     $("#login-content2").hide(0);
     $("#login-content").hide(0);
     });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background: #2980b9;
}
nav li {
  float: left;          
}

nav #login-trigger{
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
#signup{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

nav #login-content, #login-content2{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 15px;
}

nav li #login-content, #login-content2{
  right: 46px;
  width: 250px;
}

/*--------------------*/


#login #submit {
  background: #2980b9;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

#login #submit:hover,
#login #submit:focus {
  background-color: #1476b7;
} 

#login #submit:active {   
  outline: none;
}

#login #submit::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}

#login label {
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#login label input {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}


/* стили для невидимого слоя */
.fon {
position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Flyout login form</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <!-- добавляем невидимый слой -->
<div class="fon"></div>
  <!--  -->
  
  
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li id="login">
    <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
     <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="login-content">
     <form>
      <fieldset id="inputs">
       <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="email" required>   
       <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="actions">

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enter">
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> remember</label>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
           <a id="signup" href="#">SignUp</a>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>

    <div id="login-content2">
     <form>
      <fieldset id="inputs">
       <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="first name" required>  
       <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="last name" required>  
       <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="email" required>   
       <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="actions">
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enter">
       <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> remember</label>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>

   </li>
   
  </ul>
 </nav>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```